# Google Maps some XPATH selectors return data some not Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I was trying to scrape google maps. The phone and hours variable is not returning any data. Other variables work fine and return data. The XPATH is correct. I am not sure what's the issue here.

Here is the [LINK](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&sxsrf=ALeKk02Uilh4YcyM2uvYlTMt9Krvn3blHA:1598345028502&q=hvac%20companies%20leduc&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rlha=0&rllag=53272023,-113543927,339&tbm=lcl&ved=2ahUKEwi815ud-7XrAhUM9IUKHR5QBxgQjGp6BAgLEE8&rldoc=1#rlfi=hd:;si:17623949950449966677,l,ChRodmFjIGNvbXBhbmllcyBsZWR1Y1omCg5odmFjIGNvbXBhbmllcyIUaHZhYyBjb21wYW5pZXMgbGVkdWOaASNDaFpEU1VoTk1HOW5TMFZKUTBGblNVTkRNVXN6Y1ZSbkVBRQ;mv:%5B%5B53.291280099999994,-113.52307619999999%5D,%5B53.2323813,-113.6138295%5D%5D)

The other selectors like name, address, title, website return the data fine but phone and hours not returning any data.

Hoping for some answers.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import csv
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()


linksFile=open("links.txt",'r')
allLinks = linksFile.readlines()
    
for link in tqdm(allLinks):

    try:
        driver.get(link)
    except Exception:
        print('Something went wrong with the URL: ')
    
    # time.sleep(15)
    
    while True:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(text(), "Directions")] | //div[contains(text(), "Website")]'))
        )

        results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(text(), "Directions")] | //div[contains(text(), "Website")]')
        for result in results:
            # writing to the CSV file
            outFile =  open("data.csv",'a+',newline="")
            writer = csv.writer(outFile)

            business = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@role="heading"]/div')
            business.click()

            # waiting for the page to load
            WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="immersive-container"]'))
            )


            # parcing response to the scrapy selector
            response = Selector(text=driver.page_source)

            name = response.xpath('//h2[@data-attrid="title"]/span/text()').get()
            title = response.xpath('(//span[contains(text(), "Google reviews")])/parent::a/parent::span/parent::span/parent::div/parent::div/parent::div/following-sibling::div/div/span/span/text()').get()
            address = response.xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Address")]/parent::span/following-sibling::span/text()').get()
            website = response.xpath('(//a[contains(text(), "Website")])/@href').get()
            phone = response.xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Phone")]/parent::span/following-sibling::span/a/span/text()').get()
            hours = response.xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Hours")]/parent::span/following-sibling::div/label/span//btext()').get()
            total_reviews = response.xpath('(//span[contains(text(), "Google reviews")])[1]/text()').get()
            total_rating = response.xpath('(//span[contains(text(), "Google reviews")])/parent::a/parent::span/parent::span/parent::div/span/text()').get()


            input('Check: ')




            outFile =  open("data.csv",'a+',newline="")
            writer = csv.writer(outFile)
            
            vals = [name, title, address, website, phone, hours, total_reviews, total_rating]
            writer.writerow(vals)
            outFile.close()
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to share link which you are hitting. As phone and hours is not available for each location in google map.

Comment: Hi Rahul, I have updated the link in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use Java script outerHTML intead of pageSource.

```
response = Selector( driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML"))
```

Also there is an issue in xpath of Hours:

```
hours = response.xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Hours")]/parent::span/following-sibling::div/label/span//b/text()').get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Google Maps link and not google search: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Leduc+Plumbing+and+Heating/@53.274672,-113.5486679,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x539ff9a5d31a87c9:0xf494d91aafd55e55!8m2!3d53.2746688!4d-113.5464739

IT should be more stable.